# $display shows unexpected high impedance 'z' output

Tags: verilog

```
module hi (
input wire clk,
output wire [6:0] a
);

wire [7:0] b; 
assign b= 8'd24;
assign a[6:0]   = b[7:1];

initial $display ("%d", a);

endmodule
```

I get a high impedance 'z' output. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't give the `assign` statement a chance to propagate the values on the wires. The `initial` block executes first. Add a delay before the `$display`, or use `$strobe` instead.